# Customize "Add an Item" in Openerp

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I need to change the name of "add an item" in tree view. Without editing it in the **base class**.

Add an Item is triggered from "web/static/src/js/view_form.js".

SO how to change the name "Add an Item" to "Add"

```
 var $cell = $('<td>', {
        colspan: columns,
        'class': this._add_row_class || ''
    }).append(
        $('<a>', {href: '#'}).text(_t("Add an item"))
            .mousedown(function () {
                // FIXME: needs to be an official API somehow
                if (self.view.editor.is_editing()) {
                    self.view.__ignore_blur = true;
                }
            })
```

Or to Create an new js file, and how to reflect through out my project

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    openerp.web.form.AddAnItemList.include({
        pad_table_to : function() {
            var self = this;
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            //for one2may field
            self.$current.find('.oe_form_field_one2many_list_row_add a').text('Your Text');
            //for many2many field
            self.$current.find('.oe_form_field_many2many_list_row_add a').text('Your Text');
        }  
    });
}) ();
```

put the above code in your js file, i suppose you able to access the openerp instance in your js file, hope this may help you :)

Comment: Sorry Jigs, its not working, I added a new js file to my existing module and also add the dependencies in __openerp__.py, but no dice.

Comment: i have update the code bit, make it anonymous function, now it should work, i suppose your js contain only this code.